# How to trigger a build on commit to branch in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins

triggers { pollSCM('H */4 * * 1-5') } will this work for merge to branch
I see we have 3 options for triggers this seems to be fo declarative

- corn
- pollScm
- upstream

where in for scripted pipeline is that something like this
`properties([pipelineTrigger([triggers('gitPush')])])`
OR
`properties([pipelineTriggers([githubPush()])])`// With this should I also enable a option on Jenkins instance

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/) plugin.

You will need to create a **webhook** in **github** and in **Jenkins Pipeline** something like *below*.

```
triggers {
         GenericTrigger( genericVariables: [
             [defaultValue: '', key: 'commit_author', regexpFilter: '', value: '$.pusher.name'],
             [defaultValue: '', key: 'ref', regexpFilter: '', value: '$.ref']
         ],
         causeString: '$commit_author committed to $ref',
         printContributedVariables: false,
         printPostContent: false,
         regexpFilterText: '$ref',
         regexpFilterExpression: 'refs/heads/develop',
         token: '12345'
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in you Jenkinsfile. Use Only those option which you need. Remove which you don't want.

```
pipeline {
  agent any 

  triggers {
    github(
      triggerOnPush: true,
      triggerOnMergeRequest: true,
      triggerOpenMergeRequestOnPush: "source",
      branchFilterType: "All",
      triggerOnNoteRequest: false)
  }
  stages {
  ...
 }
}
```

NOTE: Make sure you have done all the webhook configuration bewteen github and jenkins. and installed webhook plaugin on jenkins